# C# Linq GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list of strings like this

"Val.1.ValueA"
"Val.1.ValueB"
"Val.1.ValueC"
"Val.2.ValueA"
"Val.2.ValueB"
"Val.2.ValueC"
"Val.3.ValueA"
"Val.3.ValueB"
"Val.3.ValueC"

How can I write a linq groupby statement to group by the first part of the string including the number? In other words, in the above case I want a list of 3 groups Val.1, Val.2, Val.3

Comment: Close voter, just because this isn't something *you* will encounter doesn't mean it's too localized to be answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String.Split()` to define your group key:

```
var groups = myList.GroupBy(x => { var parts = x.Split('.'); 
                                   return parts[0] + parts[1]; });
```

This would work regardless of the length of both parts of the key (before and after the dot).

**Edit in response to comment:**

It sounds like you want to group by a number within the string, but you do not know in advance which part constitutes the number. In this case this should work:

```
var groups = myList.GroupBy(x => 
    { 
        var parts = x.Split('.'));
        int num = 0;
        return parts[0] + parts.Where(p => p.All(char.IsDigit)
                               .First( p => int.TryParse(p, out num));
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Without more information about the formatting, the simplest is:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, 5));
```

If these are in fact not fixed length:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(s => {
     var fields = s.Split('.');
     return String.Format("{0}.{1}", fields[0], fields[1]); 
});
```

Comment: Right, I should have added more info. In my case the number be in another place in the string. In other words, it could be Val.AnotherString.2.ValueB. I'm trying to use regex

Comment: Are you saying it could be `Val.1` and `Val.X.1` mixed (here, `X` is a `string` not containing `.`)?

Comment: But the trick is I may not know before hand where the .number. is